# Flow : Error Command failed with exit code 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I am trying to use `flow` type checker in my application. I installed it and trying to run

> yarn run flow

It is giving me an error as this project runs fine on web browser. Does anyone have any idea why `flow` is getting failed ?

```
> yarn run flow                                                                                                                                              
yarn run v0.23.3                                                                                                                                              
$ "D:\ReactJS\todo-app\node_modules\.bin\flow"                                                                                                                
Launching Flow server for D:\ReactJS\todo-app                                                                                                                
Spawned flow server (pid=13704)                                                                                                                              
Logs will go to C:\Users\williams~1\AppData\Local\Temp\flow\DzCzBReactJSzBtodo-app.log                                                                          
src/App.js:34                                                                                                                                                
                      v                                                                                                                                      
 34:     this.state = {                                                                                                                                      
 35:       open: false,                                                                                                                                      
 36:       todos: [],                                                                                                                                        
 37:       notetext: ""                                                                                                                                      
 38:     };                                                                                                                                                  
         ^ object literal. This type is incompatible with                                                                                                    
 30: class App extends Component {                                                                                                                            
                       ^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                                      

src/App.js:39                                                                                                                                                
 39:     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);                                                                                                    
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `handleChange`. Covariant property `handleChange` incompatible with contravariant use in                                  
 39:     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);                                                                                                    
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment of property `handleChange`                                                                                              

src/App.js:43                                                                                                                                                
 43:     this.setState({ open: true });                                                                                                                      
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `setState`                                                                                              
 43:     this.setState({ open: true });                                                                                                                      
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `open` of object literal. Property cannot be assigned on possibly undefined value                              
 30: class App extends Component {                                                                                                                            
                       ^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                                      

src/App.js:47                                                                                                                                                
 47:     this.setState({ open: false });                                                                                                                      
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `setState`                                                                                            
 47:     this.setState({ open: false });                                                                                                                      
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `open` of object literal. Property cannot be assigned on possibly undefined value                            
 30: class App extends Component {                                                                                                                            
                       ^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                                      

src/App.js:51                                                                                                                                                
 51:     let todos = [...this.state.todos];                                                                                                                  
                                    ^^^^^ property `todos`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value                                          
 51:     let todos = [...this.state.todos];                                                                                                                  
                         ^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                                    

src/App.js:54                                                                                                                                                
 54:       text: this.state.notetext,                                                                                                                        
                            ^^^^^^^^ property `notetext`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value                                            
 54:       text: this.state.notetext,                                                                                                                        
                 ^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                                            

src/App.js:57                                                                                                                                                
         v--------------------------------------                                                                                                              
 57:     this.setState({ todos: todos }, () => {                                                                                                              
 58:       // setState is async, so this is callback                                                                                                          
 59:     });                                                                                                                                                  
         -^ call of method `setState`                                                                                                                        
 57:     this.setState({ todos: todos }, () => {                                                                                                              
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `todos` of object literal. Property cannot be assigned on possibly undefined value                          
 30: class App extends Component {                                                                                                                            
                       ^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                                      

src/App.js:60                                                                                                                                                
 60:     this.props.addTodo(this.state.notetext);                                                                                                            
                                       ^^^^^^^^ property `notetext`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value                                  
 60:     this.props.addTodo(this.state.notetext);                                                                                                            
                            ^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                                

src/App.js:98                                                                                                                                                
 98:             open={this.state.open}                                                                                                                      
                                  ^^^^ property `open`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value                                              
 98:             open={this.state.open}                                                                                                                      
                       ^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                                      

src/App.js:106                                                                                                                                                
106:               defaultValue={this.state.noteVal}                                                                                                          
                                            ^^^^^^^ property `noteVal`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value                              
106:               defaultValue={this.state.noteVal}                                                                                                          
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?                            


Found 10 errors                                                                                                                                              
error Command failed with exit code 2.                                                                                                                        
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

App.js

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import FloatingActionButton from "material-ui/FloatingActionButton";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import * as strings from "./Strings";
import * as colors from "./Colors";
import styles from "./Styles";
import ContentAdd from "material-ui/svg-icons/content/add";
import Dialog from "material-ui/Dialog";
import FlatButton from "material-ui/FlatButton";
import * as injectTapEventPlugin from "react-tap-event-plugin";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import { List, ListItem } from "material-ui/List";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "./actions/index";
import * as actions from "./actions/index";

const AppBarTest = () =>
  <AppBar
    title={strings.app_name}
    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
    style={{ backgroundColor: colors.blue_color }}
  />;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    injectTapEventPlugin();
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      todos: [],
      notetext: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleCreateNote = () => {
    let todos = [...this.state.todos];
    todos.push({
      id: todos.length,
      text: this.state.notetext,
      completed: false
    });
    this.setState({ todos: todos }, () => {
      // setState is async, so this is callback
    });
    this.props.addTodo(this.state.notetext);
    this.handleClose();
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  _renderTodos() {
    return this.props.todos.map(event => {
      return (
        <ListItem
          primaryText={event.text}
          key={event.id}
          style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}
          onTouchTap={this._handleListItemClick.bind(this, event)}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  _handleListItemClick(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <AppBarTest />
          <FloatingActionButton
            style={styles.fab}
            backgroundColor={colors.blue_color}
            onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}
          >
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
          <Dialog
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
            title={strings.dialog_create_note_title}
          >
            <TextField
              name="notetext"
              hintText="Note"
              style={{ width: "48%", float: "left", height: 48 }}
              defaultValue={this.state.noteVal}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onKeyPress={ev => {
                if (ev.key === "Enter") {
                  this.handleCreateNote();
                  ev.preventDefault();
                }
              }}
            />

            <div
              style={{
                width: "4%",
                height: "1",
                float: "left",
                visibility: "hidden"
              }}
            />

            <FlatButton
              label={strings.create_note}
              style={{ width: "48%", height: 48, float: "left" }}
              onTouchTap={this.handleCreateNote}
            />
          </Dialog>

          <List style={{ margin: 8 }}>
            {this._renderTodos()}
          </List>

        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    todos: state.todos
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.48.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "babel-version": "babel --version"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- if you can break this question down it will be easier for people to answer. For example, a lot of your type errors are similar -- maybe you could create a minimal example that exhibits one type error and focus the question on that.

Comment: you have 10 errors which needs to be fixed. for example first error you haven't defined the type of state object.  `this.state = { open: Boolean,todos: Array,notetext: string}`

Comment: @SlimShady It doesn't required in react. How would I declare and initialize a variable ? `open: false` which I did in `this.state` to get it worked

Comment: Flow is static Type checker but you arent mentioning the type of variables. Then why are you even using flow for ? read more here https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/types-and-expressions/

Comment: @SlimShady can you answer so I can accept it

Comment: @SlimShady btw whats a default of these data types ? null or what ? do you have any link ?

Comment: The `flow` would exit if the error or warning exists. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5009

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flow at its core is a type system Which adds static type checker to javascript.

In javascript you can do things like

```
    const add = (a,b) => {
     return a+b;
    }
   add(6,9); // 15
   add("6","9"); // 69
   add("Slim ","Shady");//Slim Shady
```

But using flow you need to define the types of variables in the function.

```
   const add = (a: number,b: number): number => {
     return a+b;
    }
       add(6,9); // 15
       add("6","9"); // error
       add("Slim ","Shady");// error
```

Its profitable to use it in big projects which has many people contributing because it becomes confusing without static type checker. And projects which needs to be documented heavily.

Wont really recommend to use in small projects unless the team really needs it. And wont use in every js file because sometimes static typing can be pain

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is almost entirely incorrect. Flow is a static type system, but it does *not* require manifest typing. Your original example—without types—is perfectly fine, because Flow can *infer* the types: [demo](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwTAvDAFHANAIwJSoB8MA3gFAyWUBOAplAK7VjwDUOA3BVQL7fxJ0ANiwBOPBxgB6KTACMAVn6IE6AERC1WNaLUTpsoaOWC1AZQA2ASwC2MLeYAWiAJ56OMy7ZhnnCF0A). (I also disagree with the suggestion not to use it in small projects. Flow has a very low barrier to entry. In my experience, static typing is only a "pain" if your code is already broken.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error code when running yarn install.
here is how I solved it:

clean npm caches:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

re install npm globally

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

then use the stable version ( or specify the version you need )

```
sudo n stable
```

If the issue still persists you can also delete your package.json & node modules and try again